# Dynamic LINQ - Dynamic, Server Side Where Clause

Tags: linq, dynamic, where-clause

I have been reading up on dynamic LINQ and predicate builders.  I'm a bit unclear and a bit confused about some of the backend logistics.  I am trying to offer a reports/advanced search option for one of my applications, involving a nasty groupwise-max query.

I can easily put this together to filter results programmatically, but, for performance reasons, I'd certainly prefer to have the where clause executed on the SQL server, and not in the .net code.  I'm unsure as to which solutions actually execute the predicates in SQL and not client/.NET side.  Here's an example of what I'd like to do with LINQ:

```
from fbd in db.FooBarDatas
join max_fbd in
    (from fbd in db.FooBarDatas
     group fbd by new { fbd.FooID, fbd.BarID } into grp
     select new { MaxFooBarDataID = grp.Max(fbd => fbd.FooBarDataID }
    )
on fbd.FooBarDataID equals max_fbd.MaxFooBarDataID
select new
{
    FooBarDataID = fbd.FooBarDataID,
    NormalizedPropertyName1 = fbd.Column1,
    NormalizedPropertyName2 = fbd.Column2,
    NormalizedPropertyName3 = fbd.Column3,
    etc...
}
```

So this is my basic query.  I throw them all into a generic link data object at the end because lots of the data that I'll want to pull dynamically from the query comes from foreign tables and I want them all to be referenced as direct properties.

Now I want a way that I can add a whole bunch of "where" clause conditions to this query in order to generate a meaningful report.  The "where" clause will be different depending on the parameters given by the user.  The record set is rather large, so again, I'm looking for a way to do the filtering on the SQL side.

Can anyone provide a simple example on how this can be accomplished?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that I found the answer after coming across a rather strange article title.

http://www.weirdlover.com/2010/05/11/iqueryable-can-kill-your-dog-steal-your-wife-kill-your-will-to-live-etc/

It seems that IQueryable does not actually do any kind of actual TSQL compilation until the iterator is requested.  Here is a very simple example:

```
// this does not actually call a TSQL query
IQueryable<FooBar> q = (from fb in db.FooBars select fb);
// this line still does not call a TSQL query
q = q.Where(fb => fb.FooID == 3);
// this line still does not call a TSQL query
q = q.Where(fb => fb.BarID == 74)
// this line finally compiles a TSQL statement, calls the query, and
// gathers the results:
List<FooBar> results = q.ToList();
```

the IQueryable object is an evaluate on demand object.  After trying it out, I found some pretty complex statements rife with UDF's were still returning back almost instantly.  Another article that explains the difference between this and server-side filtering can be found here:

http://www.sellsbrothers.com/posts/details/12614

I hope that this helps anyone else looking to do what I was doing.